# MHC-I presentation during infection

Tags: immunology

Which cell type cannot process and present antigen peptide in association with MHC-I when it is infected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All nucleated cell (cells with defined nucleus) are able to present MHC-1 on their surface.  Since red blood cells do not have nucleus, they are not able to represent antigins in MHC-1 molecule.

Hope that helps [check wikipedia for reference](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_histocompatibility_complex)